# Extract IMG tags in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Is it possible to extract the IMG tag (or just the src attribute of an IMG tag) from a block of HTML in Ruby?

For example, if I have a block of HTML such as:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, labore et dolore magna aliqua.<img src="example.jpg" alt="" /> Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
```

Could I extract just the IMG tag or src of that IMG tag via Regex or some other method?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Using [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/):

```
require 'nokogiri' # gem install nokogiri
doc = Nokogiri::HTML( my_html_string )
img_srcs = doc.css('img').map{ |i| i['src'] } # Array of strings
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use this regular expression

```
html_str[/img.*?src="(.*?)"/i,1]
```

If you want a more advance html parser, I recommend [nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/)

Comment: This doesn't work for single-quoted attribute values, upper-case tag names, other attributes (like `id` or `alt`) between the tag and attribute, extra space between the tag and the attribute. It also only finds the src for the first img, not all. Although a regex-based solution could be made better, as most other answers here show, you should generally leave XML and HTML parsing to XML and HTML parsers.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/) to parse the HTML and search for img tags to extract the src attribute from.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to do this. I prefer using the [Nokogiri gem](http://nokogiri.org/).

Before you get too far into this I suggest reading the following written by Jeff Atwood regarding parsing with Regex: [Parsing Html The Cthulhu Way](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html)